# Unable to Merge Dex - Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running the application in Android 5.1 device and it's running well after some time i have uninstalled the android studio and now i have installed Android Studio 3.0.1 and working on Elementary OS Loki and trying to run it on Android 8.0 device and when I start new app and run it then all goes well but the existing project is not running it gives error while running

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

And I have `build.gradle` file as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "za.co.neilson.alarm"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation files('lib/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
}
```

I have googled and tried other solutions like

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

And **rebuild / clean project** but it did not work

Comment: Remove implementation files('lib/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar') dependence and rebuild project no need to jar if already set gradle dependence

Comment: If I remove the implementation then there is one error with ActionBarActivity can not resolve ActionBarActivity so I have looked for solution but did not solve problem so I have downloaded .jar file and implement it as library

Comment: Use this one  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' but no need to jar file if use jar then don't use gradle

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'` there are no reasons to add the jar file (also pay attention since the aar contains the jar file but also the resources).

Remove this line:

```
implementation files('lib/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
```

and delete the `lib/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` file

> I have googled and tried other solutions like
>           multiDexEnabled true

It is completely useless in your case. Use it when your app and the libraries it references [exceed 65,536 methods](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html), not when you are adding twice the same classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your gradle version to 3.0.1 or 2.3.3. By changing to one of them it may work for you.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    //or try classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
}
```

After this clean and rebuild the project.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: In Android Studio v3.0 we can't use gradle version lower that 3